# How to limit choice field options based on another choice field in django admin

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-admin

I have the following models:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)

class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)

class Demo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item)
```

In the admin interface when creating a new Demo, after user picks category from the dropdown, I would like to limit the number of choices in the "items" drop-down. If user selects another category then the item choices should update accordingly. I would like to limit item choices right on the client, before it even hits the form validation on the server. This is for usability, because the list of items could be 1000+ being able to narrow it down by category would help to make it more manageable.

Is there a "django-way" of doing it or is custom JavaScript the only option here?

Comment: Is there really no way to set this in the Django models?

Comment: Yeah there is. With a third party app. See my answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is some javascript (JQuery based) to change the item option values when category changes:

```
<script charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
    $("select#id_category").change(function(){
      $.getJSON("/items/",{id: $(this).val(), view: 'json'}, function(j) {
        var options = '<option value="">--------&nbsp;</option>';
        for (var i = 0; i < j.length; i++) {
          options += '<option value="' + j[i].optionValue + '">' + j[i].optionDisplay + '</option>';
        }
        $("#id_item").html(options);
        $("#id_item option:first").attr('selected', 'selected');
      })
      $("#id_category").attr('selected', 'selected');
    })
  })
</script>
```

You need a view to be called on the /items/ URL that supplies a JSON list of the valid items.

You can hook this into your admin by using [model admin media definitions](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-media-definitions).

Comment: +1 -> I was about to post something very similar. The OP just needs to populate the lists using the information in the db and then switch the options using the JS you provided :-)

Comment: ...or if you don't want to load it all at once, you could use some ajax to request the category from the server each time the user changes the option. Depends whether you want to take the hit up front or delay them when they're selecting...

Comment: Thanks Jon.  If you want to, you should go ahead an post your code that populates the lists at load time instead of ajax like mine.  Then OP can choose the more appropriate.

Comment: I would if I had some to hand... AJAX is one aspect of Django I've yet to venture in to though. Soon though I'm sure :-)

Answer (score 7):

There is [django-smart-selects](https://github.com/digi604/django-smart-selects):

If you have the following model:

```
class Location(models.Model)
    continent = models.ForeignKey(Continent)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country)
    area = models.ForeignKey(Area)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    street = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

And you want that if you select a continent only the countries are available that are located on this continent and the same for areas you can do the following:

```
from smart_selects.db_fields import ChainedForeignKey 

class Location(models.Model)
    continent = models.ForeignKey(Continent)
    country = ChainedForeignKey(
        Country, 
        chained_field="continent",
        chained_model_field="continent", 
        show_all=False, 
        auto_choose=True
    )
    area = ChainedForeignKey(Area, chained_field="country", chained_model_field="country")
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    street = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Comment: Is it possible to limit the choices based on 2 fields value that has foreign key relation ? For example `city` is foreign key field

Comment: @Saidamir Doesn't look like it. I'd roll my own in your case

Answer (score 0):

You will need to have some kind of non-server based mechanism of filtering the objects.  Either that, or you can reload the page when the selection is made (which is likely to be done in JavaScript anyway).

Otherwise, there is no way to get the subset of data from the server to the client.