# Django makes strange multiple GET calls on admin-site

Tags: python, django, get

My Django-Project is making some strange faned-out GET calls when opening on model from the admin-site and i have no idea where this comes from. I will try to provide as much information possible.

Imagine this model called 'Rating', which holds a reference i.e. foreign key to 'Item', 'Usecase' and 'Rater'. So the Item can be rated under a certain case of use by some rater. Furthermore these together sould be unique.

Now when i open the list of 'Ratings' on the admin site, django blows out a couple of strange GET calls, which doesn't happen with the other models. This does even happen when there are no ratings. Actually my 'Rating' class is calles 'Testfragenbewertung' in german. This is what gets called upon clicking on the model on the admin-aite:

```
[04/Dec/2009 13:02:43] "GET /admin/MYAPP/testfragenbewertung/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3739
[04/Dec/2009 13:02:43] "GET /t HTTP/1.1" 404 1913
[04/Dec/2009 13:02:43] "GET /e HTTP/1.1" 404 1913
[04/Dec/2009 13:02:43] "GET /s HTTP/1.1" 404 1913
[04/Dec/2009 13:02:43] "GET /f HTTP/1.1" 404 1913
[04/Dec/2009 13:02:43] "GET /r HTTP/1.1" 404 1913
[04/Dec/2009 13:02:43] "GET /a HTTP/1.1" 404 1913
[04/Dec/2009 13:02:43] "GET /g HTTP/1.1" 404 1913
[04/Dec/2009 13:02:43] "GET /n HTTP/1.1" 404 1913
[04/Dec/2009 13:02:43] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 1910
[04/Dec/2009 13:02:43] "GET /j HTTP/1.1" 404 1913
[04/Dec/2009 13:02:43] "GET /t HTTP/1.1" 404 1913
[04/Dec/2009 13:02:44] "GET /e HTTP/1.1" 404 1913
[04/Dec/2009 13:02:44] "GET /s HTTP/1.1" 404 1913
[04/Dec/2009 13:02:44] "GET /t HTTP/1.1" 404 1913
[04/Dec/2009 13:02:44] "GET /f HTTP/1.1" 404 1913
[04/Dec/2009 13:02:44] "GET /r HTTP/1.1" 404 1913
[04/Dec/2009 13:02:44] "GET /a HTTP/1.1" 404 1913
[04/Dec/2009 13:02:44] "GET /g HTTP/1.1" 404 1913
[04/Dec/2009 13:02:44] "GET /e HTTP/1.1" 404 1913
[04/Dec/2009 13:02:44] "GET /n HTTP/1.1" 404 1913
[04/Dec/2009 13:02:44] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 1910
[04/Dec/2009 13:02:44] "GET /j HTTP/1.1" 404 1913
[04/Dec/2009 13:02:44] "GET /s HTTP/1.1" 404 1913
```

Is this supposed to happen, since it doesn't with any other model. As you can see those calls together are somehow the letters of the name of the class, with few exceptions. Have i overlooked something very stupidly or is it possibly a bug in my Django 1.2 pre-alpha SVN-11782? Thanks for any help or hints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd be interested to see the admin.py for that app. I'd guess there's something wrong in the media definitions for the form - the clue is the 'js' at the end of the list. You're probably using a string somewhere Django is expecting a tuple.

Comment: Thank you very much for that tip! I found the mistake when i was investigating. There was a javascript-hook left in the class meta, which i had forgotten since experimenting after this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/796466/how-to-limit-choice-field-options-based-on-another-choice-field-in-django-admin