# Many-to-Many relationship with check on Membership

Tags: django, many-to-many, models

I wish to create with a database with following models and constraints.

```
1) Student with attributes name, roll number
2) Exam with attributes exam_code, exam_subject
3) Option with attributes option_name, and ManyToManyField on Exam
4) Application with user, exam, ManyToManyField on Options(new)
```

Basically there will be many exams and options. Student is entitled to choose a subset of options pertaining to his examination choice.

edit: With the new model Application, I suppose the problem boils down to using [javascript in the interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/796466/how-to-limit-choice-field-options-based-on-another-choice-field-in-django-admin) for limiting the options available in the interface.

The next challenge lies in handling students with multiple subjects and their subset of options should be a intersection of options(as two different exams might have options in common) available for both exams. Any guidance on this part would be great.

Comment: I think I understand the problem, but could you try to reword a bit, just so I'm clear on what you are asking?

Answer (score 1):

As it stands right now, the Student doesn't really play into the equation. All that matters is what options are available for the particular exam in question (where Student is only nominally related in that the particular exam is a data point on it).

So, that being the case, the available options to a student is always a function of:

```
some_student.exam_taken.available_options.all()
```

What you may be wanting, is the ability for a student to have taken *multiple* exams, and then have all of the available options for all of the exams taken -- a sort of aggregate.

If that's the case, first, you would require a M2M relationship established between Student and Exam (instead of the Foreign Key). Then, you could get all available options from all exams via:

```
Option.objects.filter(exam__student=some_student).distinct()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer especially on the second part. But considering two exams might have common options, how can I show an intersection of options related to multiple exams as the aggregate?