# How to filter queryset of a foreignkey field in Django Admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

I have a scenario like this, I have 3 models: Category, Subcategory and Posts.

-Category is One to Many to Subcategory and Subcategory is One to Many to Posts.

My **models.py** looks like this (minified version).

```
class Category(models.Model):
    cat=models.CharField(max_length=10)

class SubCategory(models.Model):
    subcat=models.CharField(max_length=10)

class Posts(models.Model):
    cat=models.ForeignKey(Category) 
    subcat=models.ForeignKey(SubCategory) 
    title=models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

I want to publish a post from admin in which I only want the queryset of subcategories based on selected dropdown from category. Like, if I select Django from dropdown in "Add Posts" section in admin, it should only give me subcategories which were linked to Django(or whatever I choose from dropdown).

I have tried searching a lot and the best I could find is ***render_change_form***. But the problem with render_change_form is, it requires condition for filtration which I don't have as I want the Category from the form itself(based on dropdown selection).

I am not really sure if it's even possible in django.

Comment: Do you need the SubCategory select on the Post Form to be loaded dynamically every time you choose a value from the Category select? or, you just need to validate that the selected sub category belongs to the Category?

Comment: I think this is a duplicate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/796466/how-to-limit-choice-field-options-based-on-another-choice-field-in-django-admin

Comment: Imagine, I am adding a post. I have three fields to fill i.e title , cat and subcat. Title is ok. Now for Cat, I can select from dropdown. Based on this selection of cat, all the related subcategories should only be listed. For eg, I have two cats, Django and Programming, under django I have views and models and under programming, I have C++,C. So when I add a Post and select Django, the subcat should only list views and models dynamically. Is it possible ? Let me know if you want any other clarification and thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to either write your own custom javascript. So whenever category is selected, subcategory dropdown will be populated based on some ajax hit.

You may also have a look at [django autocomplete light.](https://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorial.html#filtering-results-based-on-the-value-of-other-fields-in-the-form)

I have used it many times in my project. Your requirement can be achieved using forward argument(send category to subcategory.)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, I ended up writing my own Javascript yesterday. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. In Django Admin I have two fields.

- Make (Foregin Key to Make Table)
- Model (Foregin Key to Model Table)

In frontend you can select a brand and using htmx request I call all models for this brand, save them in Model Table and show all related brands of the selected model in a select field.

Initial situation
Retrieving all models of the selected brand works perfectly in the frontend.

The problem is in the Django Admin. There I have the possibility to edit all cars. If now another brand is selected or only the model has to be adjusted, this list is not filtered and shows all models of all car brands.

[image]

I don't want to have to customize the HTML so I can include the htmx, but just find a dependency using a plugin or other way that would be easier.

Many thanks already for the help or suggestion.