# How to load values related to selected multiple options in Django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

Thank you all for always willing to help.

I have a Django app with countries and state choices fields. However, I have no idea whatsoever on how to load the related states for each country. What I mean here is, if I choose "Nigeria" in the list of countries, how can I make all Nigerian states to automatically load in the state choice field?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to limit choice field options based on another choice field in django admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/796466/how-to-limit-choice-field-options-based-on-another-choice-field-in-django-admin)

Comment: It's kinda difficult but I believe I will find a way. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create many to many field state table, then you can multiple select state as per country.

this feature available on django- country package or django- cities package.